# How to make a text work reactive with a Textfield in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, textfield, responsive

I have this code, in it I have a text and a textfield, how can I make the text fill in together with the same as the textfield in a reactive way.

This attempt to do but without getting results.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String aMostrar = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.text = "";
    controller.addListener(() {
      aMostrar = controller.text;
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TextField Example"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
            ),
            Text(aMostrar),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: You just need to call `setState` to see the changes on the Text widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get the text value from the controller as `TextField` already provides `onChanged`.

and within `onChange` you need to call `setState`.

Like below:

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      aMostrar = value;
    });
  },
),
```

If you are using `TextFormField` then you need to call `setState` inside the listener of `controller`.

Like below:

```
controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    aMostrar = controller.text;
  });
});
```